# Как сделать горизонтальный скрол блока при мобильной версии (использую бутсрап 5.1). т.е что бы можно было скролить

Tags: html, bootstrap, прокрутка

```
<section class="section-box">
          <div class="container">
          <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
  <div class="accordion-item border-accordion">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne title-accordion">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne ">Информация о транспортных средствах</button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
        <div class="mat-expansion-panel-body ng-tns-c76-0 content-accordion">          
            <app-main-info class="col-md-6 table">

    <table class="table col-md-6">
  <thead class="border-color">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">№ тягача/прицепа</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Тип TC</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Марка</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Модель</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">ГРН</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">VIN номер</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Кол-во осей</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Масса без груза (т)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-line">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-line">
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Semitrailer</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>   
</app-main-info>
</div>     
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Оказалось все просто! Надо было внимательней читать документацию бутстрапа. Таблицу обернуть <div class="table-responsive">таблица</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="section-box">
          <div class="container">
          <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
  <div class="accordion-item border-accordion">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne title-accordion">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne ">Информация о транспортных средствах</button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
        <div class="mat-expansion-panel-body ng-tns-c76-0 content-accordion">          
            <app-main-info class="col-md-6 table">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table col-md-6">
  <thead class="border-color">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">№ тягача/прицепа</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Тип TC</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Марка</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Модель</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">ГРН</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">VIN номер</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Кол-во осей</th>
      <th scope="col" class="table-col">Масса без груза (т)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-line">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-line">
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Semitrailer</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
      <td>инфа</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>   
</app-main-info>
</div>     
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]